# Blueprint-specific assets in Flask using Flask-Assets?

Tags: python, flask

I'm pretty new to Flask, for what it's worth. I'm using blueprints to break up my code and am trying to use Flask-Assets for serving up asset links. For some reason, though, I can't get Flask-Assets to work within a blueprint.

Code structure:

```
/modules
    /base
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
/static
    # ... stuff
/templates
    /layout.html
```

In /modules/base/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
from flask import current_app as app

default = Blueprint('base', __name__)

assets = Environment(app)

css = Bundle('css/bootstrap.min.css')
assets.register('css_all', css)

js = Bundle('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'js/bootstrap.min.js')
assets.register('js_all', js)

@default.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index/index.html')
```

And the base layout has this in it:

```
{% assets "css_all" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}" />
{% endassets %}
{% assets "js_all" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

Actually what I have in /modules/base/__init__.py right now doesn't even work, as it throws "RuntimeError: working outside of application context". If I move the assets code into the index function it does work, but it seems weird to have to repeat that code every time I want to add assets. Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something?

***Edit:*** Updated /modules/base/__init__.py per codecool's comment, but now it throws an "TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'assets'" error. I think this one is because the assets object isn't getting passed through to the app.

***Edit 2:*** So taking some advice from how SQLAlchemy does things, I got this to sort of work with the following:

In my main __init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from modules.base import default, assets as base_assets
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle

app = Flask(__name__) 
app.register_blueprint(default)

base_assets.init_app(app)
```

In base/__init__.py:
    from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
    from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
    from flask import current_app as app

```
default = Blueprint('base', __name__)

assets = Environment(app)

css = Bundle('css/bootstrap2.min.css')
assets.register('css_all', css)

js = Bundle('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'js/bootstrap.min.js')
assets.register('js_all', js)
```

The trick here is creating assets in the blueprint, importing it into the base init, and then calling .init_app there. Where this breaks down, however, is in having two blueprints that do this. The last one called always wins out. Maybe it'd be possible to pull this out into some common module or something..

Comment: I have edited my answer with the solution of your new problem.

Answer (score 7):

You dont need to call `_get_current_object` method on `current_app` and thats why you are getting the error. `current_app` is actually a proxy for the app. 
Code should be like this:

```
    app = current_app
    assets = Environment(app)
```

Infact, you don't need to assign it as variable. Do this:

```
     from flask import current_app as app

     assets = Environment(app)
```

You are getting RuntimeError because `_get_current_object` is available only when a request is going on otherwise you have to use `current_app`. When you moved assets initializing code inside the `index` view then it started working as it was now inside a request.

`_get_current_object`'s usage comes in Signals functionality in Flask and you can read about it here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/signals/#sending-signals.

Edit:

This is happening because this is not the right place to initialize Flask assets. It has to be initialized in `modules/__init__.py` where jinja environment is set up when app is created. 
Remember blueprints code is run only when it is accessed. All the global initializations should be done in the module where your app is defined i.e where this code is present:

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    assets = Environment(app)
```

Comment: That solves the problem of it not loading, but now it throws an error:

    `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
    
    TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'assets'.`

I think that's because the Flask-Assets object isn't actually getting appended to the Flask app object.

Comment: I've tried initializing assets in the base init as well, and that doesn't change anything. Are you saying, then, that it's not possible to have blueprints set their own assets?

Comment: @gchucky Yes! Extensions should be initialised in main __init__.py. This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

> The trick here is creating assets in the blueprint, importing it into
> the base init, and then calling .init_app there. Where this breaks
> down, however, is in having two blueprints that do this. The last one
> called always wins out. Maybe it'd be possible to pull this out into
> some common module or something..

Take a look at this article. It explains very well how to make assets blueprint-specific. https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-assets/#blueprint-specific-bundles

You can declare bundles wherever you want. In the article, they are declared in a separate file `assets.py`. Alternatively you can set up your blueprint-specific bundles where you declare the blueprints themself. Then import those to your main project `__init__.py` file, and register them after you register the blueprint.

I've modified your example here:

`/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask-assets import Environment
from modules.base import bp as base_bp, assets as base_assets
# Assuming more blueprints in addition to modules.base...
from modules.home import bp as home_bp, assets as home_assets
from modules.auth import bp as auth_bp, assets as auth_assets

# Declare Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)

# Register Blueprints
app.register_blueprint(base_bp)
app.register_blueprint(home_bp)
app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)

# Register Assets
bundles = {**base_assets, **home_assets, **auth_assets}  # Combines all bundle-dictionaries into one
assets = Environment(app)
assets.register(bundles)
```

`/modules/base/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask-assets import Bundle

# Declare Blueprint
bp = Blueprint("base", __name__)

# Declare Blueprint-Specific Assets
bundles = {
    "base_css": Bundle(
        "base/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ),
    "base_js": Bundle(
        "base/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
        "base/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    )
}

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index/index.html')
```

`/modules/base/templates/layout.html`:

```
{% assets "base_css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSET_URL }}" />
{% endassets %}
{% assets "base_js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

Comment: In your import statements (e.g., `assets as base_assets`), what is `assets`? Should that be `bundles` instead?